# Can I prevent C# code in a View from redirecting on form post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial view that can be called from anywhere on my website. When the user clicks a `submit` button in the `Partial View` an email is sent. The user is not asked for any information as this is already contained in my `Model`. The C# code is in my `Partial View` rather than my `Controller` as I needed to pass the `Model` (which contains several `arrays`) as a parameter but was unsuccessful doing so.  When the user clicks the button, the form submits and the mail sends but then the user is redirected to the address of the `Partial View`, rather than the address of the original `View` with the `Partial View` displayed. How can I prevent this redirection?

For example if `PartialView.cshtml` is loaded from `/Home/View/` I am redirected to `/Home/PartialView` on post.

PartialView.cshtml loaded from HomeController.cs via Ajax post in JQuery

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialView()
{
    ....create myModel....
    return PartialView(myModel);
}
```

PartialView.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    <input type="submit" value="email" />
}

...rest of partial view...

@{
    if (IsPost){
        ....sends email using data in model....
    }
}
```

**Previously** I had the following, but the data in the model received by the controller was always null. (not part of the question but in case someone asks why my code is not in my controller):

PartialView.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("sendMail", "Home",  FormMethod.Post, new { myModel = Model }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.firstArray);
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.secondArray);
    <input type="submit" value="email" />
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public void sendMail(myModelType myModel )
{
    ....send email using data in model....
}
```

Comment: Why not just post using ajax if you don't want to redirect? And why would you have `new { myModel = Model }` in the html attributes (I assume you think you adding it to the route values - but that would make even less sense, not to mention it would not work). And `@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.firstArray);` wont work if `firstArray` is an array or complex object - you can only bind to value types.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are returning the partial view, so of course it will redirect you to the partial view:

```
return PartialView(myModel);
```

Instead, you want to get the parent, which you can get with [ParentActionViewContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.parentactionviewcontext.aspx). Try this instead:

```
var controller = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] as string;
var action = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] as string;

return View(action, controller);
```